# JGraphT throws NoSuchMethodException when initializing case classes through ClassBasedVertexFactory

Tags: java, scala, oop, jgrapht

JGraphT's `ClassBasedVertexFactory.createVertex()` is throwing a `NoSuchMethodException` for my case classes' constructors. (The runtime reports that as `TJunction.<init>()` not being found.)

Here is my parent class:

```
package org.uom.fyp.engine

   class Node {

     private var nType: RoadStructure.EnumVal = RoadStructure.Default

     /**
      * Returns the node's type. (e.g.: <b>RoadStructure.Default</b>)
      */
     def nodeType: RoadStructure.EnumVal = nType

     /**
      * Sets the node's type.
      * @param nType The node's type.
      */
     def nodeType_(nType: RoadStructure.EnumVal) = {
       this.nType = nType
     }

   }
```

Followed by one of my case classes:

```
   package org.uom.fyp.engine

   case class TJunction(p: Edge, c1: Edge, c2: Edge) extends Node {
     val priority = p
     val converging1 = c1
     val converging2 = c2
   }
```

Here is where I'm creating my vertices:

```
 def createLaneSlice(network: RoadNetwork, start: Node = null, edgeType: RoadStructure.EnumVal): Edge = {
  var vertexFactory: ClassBasedVertexFactory[Node] = null
  if (edgeType == RoadStructure.TJunction) {
    vertexFactory = new ClassBasedVertexFactory(classOf[TJunction])
  } else if (edgeType == RoadStructure.Roadabout) {
    vertexFactory = new ClassBasedVertexFactory(classOf[Roundabout])
  } else if (edgeType == RoadStructure.Crossroads) {
    vertexFactory = new ClassBasedVertexFactory(classOf[Crossroads])
  } else {
    vertexFactory = new ClassBasedVertexFactory(classOf[Node])
  }

  var v1: Node = null
  if (start == null) {
    v1 = vertexFactory.createVertex()
  } else {
    v1 = start
  }
  val v2: Node = vertexFactory.createVertex()
  network.addVertex(v1)
  network.addVertex(v2)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with scala, but obviously, this "case class" thingy does not have a public no-args default constructor. I'm not sure whether something like `def this() = this(null,null,null)` in `TJunction` could already resolve this. Otherwise, you may probably create your own vertex factory. You don't have to use the built-in `ClassBased...` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the custom constructor from my case class and replacing it by setters for the subsequent properties does the trick.

Thanks to @Marco13 for his enlightening comment.